# Do window.postMessage() works across different app on different Servers?

Tags: javascript, ibm-cloud

So, I have an app running on Bluemix (lets say route is- myapp1.mybluemix.net)
and I have a second app (route - myapp2.mybluemix.net).
Now I want to send message through

postMessage("Hello","http://myapp2.mybluemix.net") from myapp1.mybluemix.net.

If I do this with both Apps in one ear or package the server and deploy it on Bluemix. I am able to do that. But not with different apps.

I don't understand the behaviour. Please help. 
Following the code for App1 -

```
<script>  
 function Menu() {
     var child = window.open("http://myapp2.mybluemix.net/page2.jsp",'name',width=200,height=200);
   child.onload=function(){
    child.postMessage('hellow','http://myapp2.mybluemix.net/');
    }
  };
  </script>
  <input type="button" value="Try it" onclick="Menu()"/>
```

And for App2(which is http://myapp2.mybluemix.net/page2.jsp)-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function listenMessage(msg) {
alert(msg.data);
 }
 window.addEventListener("message", listenMessage, false);

</script>
<p id="message">This is an Example!</p>
```

Comment: maybe some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) will help you understand

Comment: Yes, I googled it like 100 times, but I dont understand. Ideally, it should work.

Comment: as you have posted no details of how these two "apps" coexist then I can only assume you have misunderstood when and how postMessage works - the clue is that there are frames (iframes) and/or window.open involved ... you can't communicate like this across two different tabs in a browser, or two different browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed the problem.

The `postMessage` code itself is fine. It isn't working because you are never calling it.

**The `load` event can't be detected across origins.**

Have App 2 listen for its own `load` event and use `window.opener.postMessage` to announce to App 1 when it is ready.

Comment: I have edited the code and removed the child.onload, but now I want to send some data from App1 to App2 and manipulate it in App2. I dont know why the message is not going from App1 to App2, although the message from App2 are successfully received by App1.